# MongoDB PHP - Limit and Skip not Working

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I am trying to limit a query return length with limit and skip but the returned array is an empty array. Here is the code snippet,

```
$start = 0;
$limit = 10;
$options = [
    'skip' => $start,
    'limit' => $limit,
];
$return = $db->collection->find([], $options);
```

- Collection has data (243 documents/rows to be exact)
- only find([]) does return those rows
- Im using mongodb/mongodb library via composer
- MongoDB PHP Plugin is the new one, installed via PECL mongodb-1.2.9

Is there something I am doing wrong? Is this a bug or a random thing?

Regards

*PS: I know this is an already asked question, but most of the answers are related to the older extensions.*

Comment: you defined $limit but not $per_page , should use $limit?

Comment: sorry... that the change i forgot to make during posting. in my code $per_page is set. Let me correct the code snippet. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I just let the script run and it is returning rows but not showing them in var_dump. Is this the default behavior because I could view the rows in var_dump when no limit/skip is applied.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official Mongo DB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.2/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-find/) what you have done is correct.

The second `$options` argument to the `find($filter, $options)` method supports the `limit` and `skip` keys, e.g.:

```php
$options = [
    "limit" => 10,
    "skip" => 0
];

$results = $mongoCollection->find([], $options);
```